# How to convert same column different rows to different column same row in SQL?

Tags: sql, pivot

This is what I want to do.

```
----input table----

SID | VALUE
1   |  v1
1   |  v2
1   |  v3
1   |  v4
1   |  v5
2   |  s1
2   |  s2
2   |  s3

---output table----
sid | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
1   |  v1  |  v2  |  v3  |  v4  |  v5
2   |  s1  |  s2  |  s3  |  ''  |  ''
```

Comment: Google for ___sql pivot query___

Comment: It's called a pivot; search it and give a go at implementing what you find. You'll also find some good tips by searching "conditional aggregation" which is an alternative technique for databases that don't have a dedicated pivot keyword

Comment: This is better done in your application when you _display_ the data

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern of a conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  sid,
  MAX(CASE WHEN value = 'v1' THEN value END) as col1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN value = 'v2' THEN value END) as col2,
  ...
FROM t
GROUP BY sid
```

Il leave it for you to put the other columns in as a practice:)

I prefer to put the value as the column name, not col1, col2 etc

Also if you really want empty strings rather than nulls for those last two columns you can modify the case when to have ELSE '' (note: won't work if you use MIN instead of max) or use COALESCE around the MAX

Answer (score 0):

Learn pivot

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

do something like

```
  select *
    from 
    (
      select sid, value
      from table_name
    ) src
    pivot
    (
      sid
      for sid in ([1], [2])
    ) piv;
```